# Spring Security - Further Restricting Methods

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I have an application that is authorizing an OAuth2 token with Spring Security.  Using the @PreAuthorize tag, I can easily make sure that a user has a permission before allowing them to access a method:

```
@PreAuthorize("#oauth2.hasScope('account.read')")
public void getAccount(int accountId);
{
    //return account
}
```

This works great at restricting users without the *account.read* permission from accessing this method.

The only problem is now *any* user with this permission can access *any* account.  I want to restrict the users to only access their own account.  I'm sure this is a common scenario.  How do other applications deal with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the question here - how would system know if account belongs to user?
The answer would be that you are probably storing User<->Account relationship in the database. The most simple solution would be to do the check right in your method:

```
@PreAuthorize("#oauth2.hasScope('account.read')")
public Account getAccount(int accountId) {   
    // get account from db
    Account account = repository.findById(accountId);
    // you will need a little helper to get your User from 
    //Spring SecurityContextHolder or whatever there for oauth2
    User user = securityManager.getCurrentUser(); 
    if (account.belongs(user)) {
        return account;
    } else {
        throw new UnathorizedException("User is not authorized to view account");
    }
}
```

**Upd.** one of possible improvements may be to first get the user, get id from it and do a repository.findByIdAndUserId(accountId, userId) or somthing like that. (or even repositoryFindByIdAndUser(accountId, user))